QuotaGuard + NodeJs for Heroku static IP adress
I added QuotaGuard to my Heroku project, whitelisted the static IP adresses on Mongo and realized that I needed to use a proxy to carry the HTTP operations from Node.js.
The problem is that I don't understand how to use it, I'm trying to use https-proxy-agent like suggested in the documentation, but I'm not sure how to implement it.
The current documentation of QuotaGuard is:
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var request = require('request');
var proxy = process.env.QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL;
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy);
request({
    uri: "https://example.com/api",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    agent: agent,
    timeout: 10000,
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10,
    body: "name=john"
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log("Error" + error);
    console.log("Response: " + response);
    console.log("Body: " + body);
});


But I don't want to apply this to my entire code, there must be an easier and simpler way that exist right at the connection with Mongo.
This is my server.js where the connection is done:
// libraries
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import { HttpsProxyAgent } from 'https-proxy-agent';
// config
import { PORT, MONGO_URL } from './config.js';
// routes
import patientsRouter from './routes/patientsRouter.js';
import dentistsRouter from './routes/dentistsRouter.js';
import adminRouter from './routes/adminRouter.js';
// services
import { checkAndNotifyPatients } from './services/schedulerService.js';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(patientsRouter);
app.use(dentistsRouter)
app.use(adminRouter);
app.use(express.json()); 

const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.QUOTAGUARD_URI || 'http://myurlonlocal.com:1234');

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
      checkAndNotifyPatients();
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  });

This is where I would like to use the proxy if possible. Thank you very much
